'NoForeignKeysError' error when I try to load the app after script has been run
I am pretty new to this side of Python so anything you see here will probably be wrong.
Also, this is just a play around so if I do get the chance to publish this then I will be making it very secure don't worry!
Ok,
I am creating a page where users can upload items and the items uploaded are displayed on the index.html. I have created 2 models (trailers.db and users.db)
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dotenv import load_dotenv

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'mysecret')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///main.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'users': 'sqlite:///users.db',
    'trailers': 'sqlite:///trailers.db'
}
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'static/uploads'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    
    # Relationship with Trailer model
    trailers = db.relationship('Trailer', backref='user', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"


class Trailer(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'trailers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    make = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    model = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    features = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    is_sold = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    featured = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    upload_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    sold_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=None)
    
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)

This is how it is being created
def create_db():
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_db()
    app.run(debug=True)

I get this error. Can someone help please?
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.trailers - there are no foreign keys linking these tables. Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

I am also getting this error in my terminal when I run this python script.
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'trailers.user_id' could not find table 'users' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
If I remove these 2 lines of code that are # out then it works.
class User(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'users'
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

    # trailers = db.relationship('Trailer', backref='user', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"

class Trailer(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'trailers'
    __tablename__ = 'trailers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    make = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    model = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    features = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    is_sold = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    featured = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    upload_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    sold_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=None)
    
    # user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)


Try __tablename__ instead of __bind_key__ (or as well as)

Still getting the error, could it be something to do with my html as I am getting session['user_id'] to check if the user is logged in

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
